# Как найти минимальное значение в двух массивах?

Tags: java, массивы

Даны два массива имеющие только положительные значения. Нужно вернуть минимальное значение которое находится в обоих массивах.
Например:

```
А{3,2,5,6,4}
B{9,7,2,3,1,5}
```

То есть в данном примере минимальное значение будет 2.

Написал вот такой код:

```
public static int solution(int[] A, int[] B) {
    int min = A[0];
    for(int i=1; i<A.length; i++)
    {
        if(min > A[i])
        {
            min = A[i];    
        }
    }
    for(int j=0; j<B.length; j++)
    {
        if(min == B[j])
        {
           System.out.println(min);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(min);
    return min;
}
```

Знаю что не работает как надо но не знаю как доделать. 
Может нужна рекурсия?

Comment: найдите пересечение двух массивов и возьмите минимум

Comment: То есть найти значение которое присутствует в одном и другом массиве а далее что? Бежать по каждому и спрашивать минимальное ли это значение?

Comment: отсортировать. или сразу отсортировать, потом двумя указателями пойти по обоим массивам до переченеия значений

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для разнообразия вот Java-8. Самое простое решение обладает сложностью `O(A.length*B.length)`, :

```
public static OptionalInt solution(int[] A, int[] B) {
    return IntStream.of(A).filter(x -> IntStream.of(B).anyMatch(y -> x == y)).min();
}
```

Здесь создаём поток элементов одного массива и фильтруем по элементам другого массива. Если совпадающих элементов нет (или один из массивов пуст), получим пустой `OptionalInt` в результате.

Если массивы большие, можно один из массивов отсортировать и воспользоваться бинарным поиском:

```
public static OptionalInt solution(int[] A, int[] B) {
    int[] sortedB = B.clone(); // менять аргумент некрасиво, делаем копию
    Arrays.sort(sortedB);
    return IntStream.of(A).filter(x -> Arrays.binarySearch(sortedB, x) >= 0).min();
}
```

Здесь амортизированная сложность будет `O((A.length+B.length)*log(B.length))`.

Примеры:

```
System.out.println(solution(new int[] {3,2,5,6,4}, new int[] {9,7,2,3,1,5}));
System.out.println(solution(new int[] {10,12,15,6,4}, new int[] {9,7,2,3,1,5}));
```

Вывод:

```
OptionalInt[2]
OptionalInt.empty
```

Comment: Супер.
Может посоветуете что-то почитать о сложности? Часто сталкиваюсь с этим но ни как не могу понять как это вычислить или написать что либо с определенной сложностью.

Comment: @tarasula, даже не знаю, что почитать. Ну если вы в цикле сперва проходите по массиву `A`, а внутри другим циклом по массиву `B`, то понятно, что сложность будет `O(A.length*B.length)`. Сложность бинарного поиска тоже известна — логарифм от числа элементов. Амортизированная сложность сортировки TimSort/QuickSort — `O(n*log(n))` (в худшем случае `O(n^2)`) — это можно посмотреть в описании этих алгоритмов в википедии, например.

Answer (score 1):

Можно не сортировать два массива, а отсортировать только первый и искать совпадения во втором массиве. Сначала берём минимум в первом массиве, потом проходим второй массив и ищем совпадение. Затем, если не нашли ничего, берём второй минимум из первого массива и опять проходим по второму. Продолжаем, пока не найдём совпадение.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SOMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = {3, 2, 5, 6, 4};
        int[] B = {9, 7, 2, 3, 1, 5};

        Arrays.sort(A);
        for (int first : A) {
            for (int second : B) {
                if (first == second) {
                    System.out.println(first);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("Совпадений не найдено");
    }
}
```

Для сравнения приведу вариант с сортировкой обоих массивов и двумя итераторами:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SOMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = {3, 2, 5, 6, 4};
        int[] B = {9, 7, 2, 3, 1, 5};

        Arrays.sort(A);
        Arrays.sort(B);

        int i1 = 0;
        int i2 = 0;

        while (i1 < A.length && i2 < B.length) {
            int cmp = Integer.compare(A[i1], B[i2]);

            switch (cmp) {
                case 1:     //  Если число из первого массива больше,
                    i2++;   //  двигаем итератор второго массива
                    break;

                case -1:    //  Если число из второго массива больше,
                    i1++;   //  двигаем итератор первого массива
                    break;

                case 0:     // Если числа совпадают, выводим результат
                    System.out.println(A[i1]);
                    return;
            }
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("Совпадений не найдено");
    }
}
```

Comment: Все понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int solution(int[] A, int[] B) {
int min = A[0];
for(int i=1; i<A.length; i++)
{
    if(min > A[i])
    {
        min = A[i];    
    }
}
for(int j=0; j<B.length; j++)
{
    if(min > B[j])
    {
       min = B[j];
    }
}
System.out.println(min);
return min;
}
```